# Oracle SQL Selecting data from one table that relates to another

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I do not have that much knowledge of SQL and it is my job to create a basic social network with friendships. To do this, I have created one table (there is more columns but I have removed them for the sake of this question);

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(USER_ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
USER_LNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
USER_FNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID));
```

I have created another table in which you can insert the user_id of two people and it generates the time in which they became friends.

```
CREATE TABLE USERFRIEND
(USER_ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FRIEND_ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
EST_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID, FRIEND_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (FRIEND_ID) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID));
```

I do not have any trouble inserting the data for either table. For example, here is a sample of the data I have inserted (my actual database has around 15 friends)

```
INSERT INTO USERS
VALUES ('10000001', 'Jones', 'Tom');
INSERT INTO USERS
VALUES ('10000002', 'Smith', 'Michael');
INSERT INTO USERS
VALUES ('10000003', 'Johnson', 'Andrew');
INSERT INTO USERS
VALUES ('10000004', 'Williams', 'David');
```

and the friendships

```
INSERT INTO USERFRIEND
VALUES ('10000001', '100000002', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO USERFRIEND
VALUES ('10000001', '100000003', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO USERFRIEND
VALUES ('10000002', '100000004', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

One of the tasks is to get a list of friends that one person has.

For example, 
Michael smith would be friends with Tom Jones and David Williams (01, 04)
My issue is that in one friendship, Michael is the user_id and in the other, the friend_id

The best result I have worked out so far is this code;

```
SELECT user_id, friend_id
FROM USERFRIEND
WHERE USER_ID = 10000002
OR FRIEND_ID = 10000002;
```

This at least returns the results of all the IDs of people that Smith (10000002) is friends with but I am not sure how to make it return this with the correlating names of those people when both USER_ID and FRIEND_ID both reference the same thing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_fname, a.user_lname, b.USER_ID, b.FRIEND_ID
FROM USERS a, USERFRIEND b 
WHERE b.USER_ID = 10000002
OR b.FRIEND_ID = 10000002;
```

I have tried this code and although in my database, there is only 20 friendships made, it returns 80 results and none of the names match up correctly.

Hopefully one of you will find the (probably simple) solution for me because I have no idea what I should be doing.

Comment: Please show an example of what you're getting for output, and what you expect that does not match.

Comment: The output was only giving the IDs

USER_ID  FRIEND_ID
-------- --------
10000002 10000009
10000008 10000009
10000009 10000010
10000009 10000012
10000009 10000013

and I could not make them correlate with the correct FNAME and LNAME because both friend ID and User ID related to the same id.

I have been given an appropriate solution below, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query above makes a cartesian product since there is no join between both the tables. You should have atleast n-1 joins where n is the number of tables used.

You can join both tables like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_fname, a.user_lname, b.USER_ID, b.FRIEND_ID
FROM USERS a, USERFRIEND b 
WHERE a.user_id=b.user_id
or a.user_d=b.friend_id
```

Comment: I tried yours and it worked, the issue was that it came up with two rows for every friendship created. 
I remedied this by adding a few more constraints and it will cancel out the person that you are actually search for

SELECT a.user_fname, a.user_lname, b.USER_ID, b.FRIEND_ID
FROM USERS a, USERFRIEND b 
WHERE (a.user_id=b.user_id
OR a.user_id=b.friend_id)
AND (b.user_id=’&USER_ID’
OR b.friend_id=’&USER_ID’)
AND a.user_id <> '&USER_ID';

So now it just lists the people associated with a specific person and doesn't include the actual person themselves.

Thank you very much for your help!